# Electroplating an iPhone

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

I thought it would be cool to electroplate the rear case of an iPhone 6 or newer since it's made out of aluminum. It's been a long time since I learned about the topic, so I looked online to research this, but hardly found anything about the topic other than some aftermarket companies that sell expensive gold electroplated iPhones. Is this a feasible DIY idea? If so, are there certain metals that would electroplate to iPhone aluminum easier than others?

Comment: Electroplating aluminum is tricky because of the adherent oxide coating, preventing plating, and because, once the coating is removed, Al reacts so quickly with aqueous solutions that the coating is not adherent.  It can be done, but may require use of cyanides, *not* for the amateur!

Comment: You could also check out anodizing for added coolness.